# Fixing ics calendar network subscriptions w/ Thunderbird 38.3. and Lightning 4.0.3

Tags: 14.04, thunderbird, calendar, lightning

This morning at boot time, TB+Lightning woke up to to zero calendar instead of its regular 2, on my Ubuntu 14.04.3 box.

The 2 calendar `-.ics` files are located on an NTFS-3g partition different from that where TB+Lightning live (ext3). I share them with other instances of Tb (never running simultaneously), such as from another Ubuntu-based or Windows boot-partition.

`file:///mnt/sda1-ntfs/path/calendar-x.ics` is the address format I have always used for those ics files.

The two calendars are shown in the calendar pane of Tb and their properties indicate that they are correctly synchronized with the files at above location. However nothing is displayed on the calendar window. Also no error.

I tried and/or checked:

- I tried unsubscribing from the ics calendar files and setting up the subscriptions again,
- I visually checked the content of said calendar files (with vim); -> same state as that of power down time 8 hours before, but they are also not garbled in any way (perfect ics format). ALL events past and future are present in them, along with all alarms entries, etc..
- I created wholly new calendars (new name) with a new subscription setup.

Nothing works. The file are there, but it is as if TB did not recognize or admit non-local ics calendars.  
As a stop gap, I resorted to just the usual "*local*" ics file and of course importing the whole content of both previous calendar files in new calendars in Lightning. Those new local calendars are well displayed. 
As an additional headache I now have  8 calendars on Lightning: the 2 original non-local ones, and 4 additional non-local ones created in the course of my troubleshooting, plus the 2 local calendars. There is apparently no way to get rid of the 6 non-local calendars on the calendar pane. Restarting TB does not help.

I reinstalled Tb with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall thunderbird` to no avail.

Any idea (short of purging the package and reinstalling it) which might rid me of a corrupt profile ?

Comment: Why the minus vote please ?

Comment: I upvoted you. No idea why somone downvoted you. Hope someone is able to help you.

Comment: @iamatrain:  Tx. Puzzled too. Might be because my post is too chatty and/or my terminology somewhat not standard. Chatty posts (Q or A) are generally bad form.

Comment: "Have they gone buggy?" is an opinionated question and cannot be answered.  Please [edit] your question and clearly state what you're trying to accomplish...  **;-) :P**

Comment: I did not mean it that way, but title fixed. Thank you for the heads-up, @Fabby. Much appreciated.

Comment: The crowd here is sometimes weird sometimes, but we'll assimilate you!  **:D**  (+1)

Comment: @Fabby: Yeah, just try me (!) and that thing about "all resistance is futile" ... Mmmh , I have this deja-vu feeling from someplace in the 3rd quadrant....    ;-D !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No good news. My solution was:

- Delete profile `profile.ini`
- Restart TB

If nothing changes, backup email, calendar(s) and contacts and reinstall TB from scratch with `sudo apt-get purge thunderbird` followed by `sudo apt-get install thunderbird`

You will have to reconfigure your chat accounts and feed subscriptions if any.